# Testing a prediction hypothesis

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I wish to test the following Hypothesis:

H = "sales growth from previous year" predicts "sales growth this year"

I have the following data:

```
> head(x)
  Location Week Sales_Y1 Sales_Y2 Sales_Y3  Y2_vs_Y1  Y3_vs_Y2
1      1_1    5 24924.50 21665.76 23510.49 0.8692556 1.0851449
2      1_1    6 46039.49 37887.17 36988.49 0.8229277 0.9762801
3      1_1    7 41595.55 46845.87 54060.10 1.1262231 1.1539993
4      1_1    8 19403.54 19363.83 20124.22 0.9979535 1.0392686
5      1_1    9 21827.90 20327.61 20113.03 0.9312673 0.9894439
6      1_1   10 21043.39 21280.40 21140.07 1.0112629 0.9934057
```

So my Hypothesis is that Y2_vs_Y1 predicts Y3_vs_Y2.

The simplest form of this hypothesis could be

> Y3_vs_Y2 = [ Y2_vs_Y1 + or - 5%]

How can I test this hypothesis?

Comment: I believe to do this properly you will need to use time series analysis. Perhaps, apply ARIMA and look for a trend. How much data do you have?

Comment: I have thousands of data.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex of a model you want to look at, this could be as simple as looking at and testing the autocorrelation.  A little more complicated is fitting an ARIMA model.  More general is fitting a dynamic linear model (which would allow you to bring in other predictors as well).

Comment: Time recurrent neural nets have been used for this kind of thing.

Comment: As stated this is simply a test of lag1 autocorrelation. DW statistics and derived statistical tests should be sufficient.